# OpenGL Hooking -- Rendering to an arbitrarily-sized FBO

Tags: c, linux, opengl, hook, glx

So I'm trying to make an OpenGL application render at a higher resolution than it normally would. I've already created a shared library that hooks most of the relevant GLX/OpenGL functions. Here's my current approach (at a high-level):

```
When my hooked SwapBuffers() is called
    Unbind my FBO
    Call the (original/unhooked) SwapBuffers()
    Bind my FBO
    Set the viewport to (0, 0, HIGH_RES_X, HIGH_RES_Y)
    Set the scissor region to (0, 0, HIGH_RES_X, HIGH_RES_Y)
    return
```

This approach doesn't seem to work for (most) applications. I suspect that is because some applications perform texture lookups (for screen-space operations) by dividing `glFragCoord.xy` by a uniform that represents their screen resolution (to convert from screen space to texture coordinates).

If resizing the output isn't possible, I wonder if it is possible to obtain the contents drawn onto the default framebuffer (i.e both the color and the depth buffer) without using `glReadPixels`. Ideally there would be a way to access this data in the form of a texture (so it's already on the GPU). I've heard things about Pixel Buffer Objects -- would using one of these prevent a pipeline stall?

Comment: This approach isn't going to work for *any* application that renders to its own framebuffers. They have to bind them every frame, and thus set the viewport and whatever else as they see fit.

Comment: My original approach also hooked glBindFramebuffer so that it would replace calls to glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0) to bind my framebuffer instead. Other glBindFramebuffer calls would be unaffected. I'd also hook glViewport to make sure that the rendering resolution is always what I want, assuming that a different FBO isn't bound.

Comment: That too is broken. The default framebuffer does not behave like a normal FBO. For example, the `glDrawBuffers` enumerators are completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique I proposed actually works for a handful of applications, but most of the time it just doesn't work.

If you just want to extract the color/depth buffer, you can either use a pool of PBOs with glReadPixels or use glBlitFramebuffer. The former is not an option if latency is a concern; the latter works fairly well (see this [example](https://github.com/crosire/reshade/blob/b180ff3f250610799fb435aa32efc5550816487e/source/opengl/opengl_runtime.cpp#L426) from the [reshade](https://github.com/crosire/reshade/) project)